# OpenGL: get the size of a type with its symbolic macro

Tags: c++, c, opengl, types

Symbolic constants are often used to pass type information in OpenGL, eg:

```c
// Can be GL_BYTE, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, GL_INT, etc...
glVertexAttribPointer(/*...*/, GL_FLOAT, /*...*/);
```

I searched to see if there was a function in openGL to get the size of that sort of constant, but couldn't find much about it, so I'm asking here. (beyond just brute forcing it).

```c
// Works but not very elegant and error prone
size_t foo(GLenum type) {
    switch(type) {
        case GL_INT:
            return sizeof(GLint);
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

Comment: No, there's not such function in OpenGL. Just roll your own.

Comment: [Here's mine](https://gist.github.com/davawen/af1490ffb3bbcf9ddc0cbab82e9f27aa), if someone stumbles on it (most probably missing the more exotic types but hey it works for me)